# Binding active but not presenting data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, textbox

I've designed a text box like this.

```
<TextBox x:Name="OrderId" 
         Text="{Binding CurrentOrder}"/>
```

In the view model I can see that the breakpoint hits both setter and getter and the value returned **is** the value supposed to.

```
public Order CurrentOrder
{
  get { return _currentOrder; }
  set
  {
    _currentOrder = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

However, nothing appears in the box. I also type in a number in the box myself, by hand and then caused the binding to update the value from the source back to the control. It cleaned the box dry. Like if *null* were written in there... Of course I've checked that there are no *null* values in the order.

1. What can I be doing wrong?
2. How to troubleshoot it?

Of course, I've tested the different one-way, two-way etc. modes. No avail. Is it by any chance required to put the notification method call on the setter of the properties in the *Order* class too? Even if it's not intended for two-way mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with how to troubleshoot it:

1. **First**, before anything else, check your output window. Are there any `System.Data` exceptions that would indicate the binding has an error?
2. Check the element in a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). It will usually show any binding errors.
3. Do some of the things you have already done, make sure the setter gets called, *then* the getter to prove the binding is evaluating.

Now as to what could be going wrong:

1. From what I can see, you are binding `Text` directly to an object. Unless that object overrides `ToString()`, that will normally not work as you expect.
2. From the above, typing in a string manually will be *very* confusing to the runtime, as it won't know how to convert the string into the object. The behavior you see makes sense unless you use a converter
3. And of course, if you use a converter, you need to check breakpoints/data in *that* code to make sure its working as expected.
4. To your edit, if you are binding to a *property* of a class, and want code changes to that property to propagate to the UI, yes it needs to raise `PropertyChagned` and the class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: You were right spot on with the output. That's the problem. I got mislead by the fact that I **do** have an overriden *ToString* there, so I expected it to work. But maybe it's not always kicking in? It's only from the source to the GUI, so I need not to worry about the other way. However, how can I pin the box's text to the property *Id* in the order bound to?

Comment: @KonradViltersten `{Binding CurrentOrder.Id}` ought to do the trick. Note that only changes to `CurrentOrder` will cause this to update unless `Order` implements INPC as in my last point.

Comment: I'd need to go something like *Text="{Binding CurrentOrder.Id}}* but, obviously , that's wrong...

Comment: Because the stupid compiler sneaked in a curly brace without me knowing it...?   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten Ah, I missed that too :) should work without the extra brace

Comment: Yes, I'm deeply disappointed in you not seeing an extra and unexpecte curly brace in italic. You should be ashamed! You should've thought of that before I did it...   :)

Comment: Now a serious follow up - should I bind the current order to a component lower in the hierarchy and then only bind to the exact property needed? I'll have a couple of those text boxes. Would be cleaner if the grid holding them bound to the order and the boxes only to that bindings properties. Doable? Recommended?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Doable, yes, recommended, only if you have a really good reason to. I find the longer strings easier to understand (rather than having to traverse back up the tree to figure out what the `DataContext` currently is). I'd leave it just as you have it.